# local wifi network on linux, IoT

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

How to create a local wifi network from a host device, which would allow other guest devices to connect the host device (just connect to its IP and port on the local network and open a TCP socket)?

** all devices are running a Debian derived linux distro

Comment: Its unclear what you atr asking - Assuming there is not already another router servicing the wofi  network - You effectively want to turn (or largely turn) the Linux box into a router.  You will want to (a) set up a DHCP server on it (b) use hostapd to turn your WIFI nic into an AP.

Comment: If your boxes already all have a connection in yhe same LAN, you can just work at the IP level and dont need to do anything special (other then maybe allow the ports through the firewall)

Comment: No guests have to give the host some info, they are not connected to a router or sth

Comment: Specifically the actual wifi network name and password

Comment: @kebadubaj your ladt comment makrs no sense to me.  Hostapd can set an SSID and password.